# Help with money on a losing side in League of Legends

Tags: league-of-legends

What are some good tips/ideas/strategies for a team or individual to put in place on a losing side when needing more money (For items etc).

As an example, Ashe often requires very expensive items but if your side isn't able to generate as much money (creep kills or whatever) then it can put you out of the game...

Not dying is too obvious!

Comment: If you're on the losing side there is usually one champion on the opposing team who has collected most of the kills. If your team can coordinate an attack on them then the extra bounty can be well worth it, even if you lose a teammate in the process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Play more defensively, allowing some of you to avoid team fights and farm minions later on
- Try to have your team get the dragon whenever possible (ward it and be careful)
- Spread your buys across more base items rather than rushing for each final piece
- If no one is jungling, you can pop in for some easy creep kills on the way to your destination or around your current area
- **Never** stick to a static build; always change it up depending on the way the game progresses

Comment: Thanks, those are some well thought out points...subtle, but clearly useful from experience...